# DAX Year over Year in line chart

Tags: sum, dax, calculated-field, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to write a DAX expression for calculating the year over year in a line chart.  The problem is that my DAX expression is resulting in a flat line and not calculating it as one day's payment amount over the TOTAL payment amount.  e.g. In this example, I'm only trying to display only one month.  When I use a Date column as my Axis, it displays correctly as below (CRD).  But when I use a Text column representing the day, it displays a flat line.  (My code for CRD Day is FORMAT([CRD],"dd")).
[image]
[image]

I also created these two measures and displayed them in this table which shows that it is not using the TOTAL payment amount for the denominator.

```
MTD RT % = [MTD Running Total] / [Total Payment Amount]
MTD RT2 % = CALCULATE(SUMX(VALUES(Cash_Goals_Cash_Velocity[CRD]), [MTD Running Total] / [Total Payment Amount]),ALL(Cash_Goals_Cash_Velocity[net_payment_amount]))
MTD Running Total = TOTALMTD(SUM([net_payment_amount]),Cash_Goals_Cash_Velocity[CRD])
Total Payment Amount = CALCULATE(SUM(Cash_Goals_Cash_Velocity[net_payment_amount]),ALL(Cash_Goals_Cash_Velocity[CRD]))
```

This table looks like below.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I do this in Power BI?
[image]

Comment: If you drag `[Total Payment Amount]` to the values chart, is it showing the values correctly?

Comment: Yes, it displays the same values as MTD Running Total.  So it looks like the column "MTD Running Total" isn't displaying a running total.  It's the "MTD RT %" column that appear to be doing all of the running total work.

Comment: The problem is your running total, it is evaluating the payment amount in each date but doesn't calculate the cumulative total, Is CashGoalsCashVelocity a date table? Note can only use Date columns with TOTALMTD functios, I recommend you create a Calendar/Date table or using explicit filter. add sample data in order to help you.

Comment: I just now removed the CRD Day column from the above table, and now MTD Running Total displays a running total like it should.  So this "CRD Day" Text column seems to be causing problems.  And yes, "MTD Running Total" is using a Date column.  Again, this column is working correctly when the "CRD Day" column is removed.

Comment: How would a Calendar/Date table be an improvement on the CRD column, which is already Date datatype?

Comment: Time intelligence functions like TOTALMTD require in most cases Calendar/Date tables. CRD Day have unique values or it repeats across multiple months i.e january has CRD Day 1, is there the same value for february?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134802/discussion-between-salvationishere-and-alejandro-zuleta).

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't require [CRD Day] column at all. Just change the settings for presentation in the visualizations properties.

[image]

Remove `Year`, `Quarter` and `Month` leaving only `Day`.

You will get something like the below image using this DAX expressions:

```
Running Total = CALCULATE(SUM([Payment]),FILTER(ALL(Table),Table[CRD] <= MAX([CRD]) ))

MTD RT % = [Running Total] / [Total Payment Amount]
```

[image]

With your running total measure should work too.

Comment: Thanks but I figured out the answer and will post on Monday. But does your solution produce a running total like I want?

Comment: @salvationishere, Yes it does, It is a different approach to calculate cumulative totals with dates.